# child parent communication best practices in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, viewchild

I'm trying to become better at Angular and I want to know the best practices between child-parent communication. My current app I want to work on is on Angular 6. I know I can  communicate between child-parent components using @ViewChild, @Output or creating a service. Is there another way to do the communication? if not which one of those 3 is better and why?

Here's a simple example:

**Child HTML**

```
<button (click)="onLinkedClicked();">Click me</button>
```

**Child TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
.
.
.
export class showcaseMenuComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() public linkedClicked = new EventEmitter<String>();

    constructor() {}

    onLinkedClicked() {
        console.log('on click child');
        this.linkedClicked.emit('collapsed');
    }
}
```

**Parent HTML**

```
<showcase-menu #topNavMenu 
               [showBranding]="false"
               [showSearch]= "false"  
               (linkedClicked)="linkToggler($event)">. 
</showcase-menu>
```

**Parent TS**

```
.
.
.
 navMenuState: string;
.
.
.
  linkToggler($event) {
    console.log("partent");
    this.navMenuState = $event;
  }
```

Comment: use rxjs subject instead of output

Comment: @Chellappan cool! Why is this one better? do you have a good example I can follow to create the simple communications between child-parent?

Comment: The [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) lists a few more ways to structure the communication, but it's basically impossible for us to say which is "better" without a lot more information about your intended use-case.

Comment: @Vlad274 I just added some simple code example to the question

Comment: @Chellappan I put a simple code example in the question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Obviously it depends on what you want to do.

**@Input**

By using `@Input` you are passing a parameter to a child component directly.
Moreover you are coupling components by putting one inside the other.
This approach is useful and simple.

It is a good approach when you want to ensure that a child component is integrated into a parent component that share a particular object and you don't have to care about synchronism mechanisms.

That means that if you change a property of the object, the object reference is still the same, so it is updated into parent and component. But if you change object reference (for example instantiating a new one or retrieving a new object by a remote service) in one component, the other one can't detect object change, so you will have a data misalignment.

**@Output**

By using `@Output` you are emitting an event upwards, so this approach is useful when you want to communicate to the parent that something is happened. Data exchange is possible but it is not the focus of the thing.

The focus is that something is happened, for example in a wizard you could have some step and each step can advise parent component that that particular step is completed. Parent does not need to know what how is happened, but only that is happened so it can go to the next step.

**@ViewChild**

By using `@ViewChild` you are getting child component reference into parent component.

You are forcing the parent to have a particular child component to work by mixing their logic.

This is useful when you want to call some method of the child component into the parent component.

Using the wizard example you can think about this situation:

- we have 3 step
- 3rd step completes and emits an `@Output` event to the parent
- parent catches the event and tries to save data
- data saving ok => parent tells last step component to show successful message
  or
- data saving fail => parent tells last step component to show fail message

**Service**

By using an external service you are centralizing data into one external object that is responsible to manage and update data.

This is a good approach for situations in which data can be retrieven from remote services or data object references can be reassigned.

Moreover by this approach you are decoupling all your components from each other. They can work without worry themselves about others' behaviours.

Generally `Subject` are used into service communication.

You can find [doc here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

**Subject VS @Output**

`Subject` uses a data driven approach.
`@Output` uses an event driven approach, or better a [Reactive Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming) approach

So meanwhile `@Output` is the preferred way when you want to communicate that an event is happened, `Subject` is the preferred approach to communicate that data are changed.

> A Subject is both a source of observable values and an Observable
>   itself. You can subscribe to a Subject as you would any Observable.

That means that you can use `Subject` to observe a particular variable or value (`Subject` as `Observer`), it detects observed value changes and emits a sort of event.

In the meanwhile you can have many other observer that are observing the  `Subject` (`Subject` as `Observable`) by subscribing to subject's events.

When subject observed value changes, all subject's subscribers are advised.

An example could be a ticketing application. One user loads the component responsible of showing free remaining places. He is thinking on which place to choose. In the meanwhile another user buy a ticket, so his place is now unavailable. First user now should see that place as unavailable, so you need to refresh data asking them to remote services (maybe with a polling alghoritm). When new data are retrieven you pass new data into `Subject.next()`. `Subject` detects that observed value is changed and advices all his subscribers that the value is changed. Obviously `Subject` pass new data to subscribers.

Comment: Last question, when to use use rxjs subject instead of output? or since is use inside of a service I apply the service "rules"

Answer (score 2):

In the situation you have shown, my preference would be to use `@Output` as you have done.

It's unlikely that a link being clicked is a wide concern, so I don't think a service makes sense.

`@ViewChild` could work, but it makes the component less reusable. If you wanted to reuse the child component inside a different parent, you'd have to copy code over.

Using `@Output`, if you wanted to use the child component in a different parent, no extra code needs to be copied over and you can bind to the `@Output` event very easily.

Comment: Cool! Correct me if I&#39;m wrong.  Let&#39;s prettend that this example has a grandchild. If I want to do the communication between Parent and grandchild component I can do the same I did in my code right? Or I have to communicate between the and grandchild and child 
 first then from child to parent?

Comment: @PatricioVargas You'd have to pas the `@Output` through the child, but I'd still say this is good for the same reasons, then both the child and grandchild are then more reusable. However, some people argue to use a service when things start getting complex like this. I don't think that's bad _per se_. At the end of the day, it should be whatever will be easiest for someone to understand 6 months later. I err on the side of simplicity - `@Output` is easy - but that's (admittedly) just my opinion

Comment: This make total sense. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

You can subject to Share Data between multiple Component

Create Service

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';    
    @Injectable()
    export class ChildParentService {

     data=new Subject();
      constructor() { }

    }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/child-to-parent-bntt2h

Answer (score 0):

Use service communication between parent and children when:

1.You want to pass data from parent component to multiple child components.

2.Several child components has the same EventEmitter that will be dispatched to the parent component.