# Parent and Child communication in Angular

Tags: angular

I have two questions:

1. If we send any variable from parent to child and than any changes  (let's say value change) in Child component. This changes will automatically reflects in Parent component or not? if not how can I reflect back?
2. I have a demo for this in which Parent comp is sending an array to child as (child has add/edit functionality). Whenever I am adding or updating any element changes is being reflected in parent comp as well (I am displaying listing in parent template).

So initially I thought that I don't need to care about sending changes back to parent as it's already working.

However, for update I have used 2 variables editForm and edit_id which is also sent by parent to child on update when I am setting editForm = false and edit_id = 0. Changes not reflected in Parent only child variables changed.

So both are confusing me now.

What might be wrong here? Below is the link where you can find my code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rw74sc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has nothing to do with this is something related to [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

So in java script when you copy primitive types (number, string, etc.) value will be copied not the reference itself, but in case of objects reference will be copied and change will reflect to parent object as well.

Below is interesting example for both reference type and value type

```js
var obj={a:10};
var copyObj=obj;
obj.a=12;
console.log(obj.a);//example of reference type you can see the output will be 12;

var a=10;
var b=a;
b=12;
console.log(a);//example of value type here output is still 10
```

[One more related SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40433889/hard-copy-vs-shallow-copy-javascript)

There are many ways to communicate from child to parent for example you can use **[@Output](https://blog.kevinchisholm.com/angular/child-parent-communication-output/)**,**shared service**,**subject**,**eventemitter** etc

[Here is an SO ans related to child parent communication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51770232/5621827)