# Child to Parent Communication with @output()

Tags: angular, components, communication

I have a form in my `Parent Component` which has a hidden input for new password and an edit password button.

In the `Child Component` by clicking on the edit password button, a `matdialog` will be loaded and to enter enter new password and save. Since this is in a different form I should pass it to the `Parent Component`.

Can anyone help for this child to parent communication?

**Child Component**

```js
@Output() editedPassword = new EventEmitter<String>();
  saveButtonClick(){
    this.editedPassword.emit(this.myform.get('password').value);
  }
```

How can I pass this value to the parent component?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Pass data from child to parent component Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42107167/how-to-pass-data-from-child-to-parent-component-angular)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Child Component**

```js
@Output() editedEvent = new EventEmitter<String>();
  saveButtonClick(){
    this.editedEvent.emit(this.myform.get('password').value);
  }
```

**Parent HTML**

```
<child-app (editedEvent)="eventHandler($event)"></child-app>
```

**Parent Component**

```js
public newPassword: string = '';

eventHandler($event) {
  this.newPassword = $event;
}
```

You can also see a complete example [here](https://blog.kevinchisholm.com/angular/child-parent-communication-output/).

In addition there is a complete explanation about Angular child-parent communication in this answer on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51769518/child-parent-communication-best-practices-in-angular/51769870).